# curl_setopt doesnt work with url as a variable

Tags: url, variables, curl

If i go like this - it works:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Muzikos-R%C5%ABsys/192813414094112?sk=events");
```

But if i try this

```
$url = "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Muzikos-R%C5%ABsys/192813414094112?sk=events";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

it returns me a blank page;

Any ideas? Cant find the answer so far...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the exact same problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$url = "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Muzikos-R%C5%ABsys/192813414094112?sk=events";
$ch  = curl_init($url);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```