# Retrieve content of another website

Tags: php, curl, fopen, file-get-contents

I want to get the content of another page. The background is that I wanted to make an AJAX request but due to the `Same Origin Policy` I cannot do this. Now I wanted to write an own PHP script on which I make the AJAX request. The URL looks like the following:

> http://domain.com/subfolder/another_subfolder/index.php?id=1234&tx_manager_pi9[parameter]=1&tx_manager_pi9[category]=test&tx_manager_pi9[action]=getInfos&tx_manager_pi9[controller]=Finder&cHash=123456789001233455332

I tried it with `fopen`, `curl` and `file_get_contents`. Nothing from the works. The problem is if I put in the URL as string like

```
$results = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/subfolder/another_subfolder/index.php?id=1234&tx_manager_pi9[parameter]=1&tx_manager_pi9[category]=test&tx_manager_pi9[action]=getInfos&tx_manager_pi9[controller]=Finder&cHash=123456789001233455332');
```

it does work. If I put in a variable

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/subfolder/another_subfolder/index.php?id=1234&tx_manager_pi9[parameter]=1&tx_manager_pi9[category]=test&tx_manager_pi9[action]=getInfos&tx_manager_pi9[controller]=Finder&cHash=123456789001233455332';
$results = file_get_contents($url);
```

I come to a wrong page. With the specific parameter I get a result. If the parameter are not given correctly it seems that I come to a default page. I can't make a sense out of it.

The same for `curl`:

```
$curlSession = curl_init();
$options = array
(
    CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER=>false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>true
);
curl_setopt_array($curlSession,$options);
$results = curl_exec($curlSession);
```

This doesn't work. If I put in the URL as string and not as variable I get some results! I thought that the ampersand `&` or the square brackets `[]` are the problem but I cannot say this. `&` should be reserved and `[]` are no correct URL parameters. But why does the direct input work and not the variable?

I used the variable because I make some replacements with `str_replace` where I make the query more flexible.

I saw similar questions here ([cURL function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004417/curl-function-not-working), [curl_setopt doesnt work with url as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056286/curl-setopt-doesnt-work-with-url-as-a-variable)) but there was never posted a real solution.

Comment: A literal string that's assigned to a variable will work the same; the problem must be somewhere else ...

Comment: Did you set a user agent in your cURL request?

Comment: But where? A simple `file_get_contents` proves this problem. If I echo the URL first and open the URL in the browser it works. A `file_get_contents` doesn't make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I used an encoded URL as starting point. E.g.

http://domain.com/subfolder/another_subfolder/index.php?id=1234&tx_manager_pi9%5Bparameter%5D=%23%23%23param1%23%23%23&tx_manager_pi9%5Bcategory%5D=%23%23%23param2%23%23%23&tx_manager_pi9%5Baction%5D=getInfos&tx_manager_pi9%5Bcontroller%5D=Finder&cHash=123456789001233455332

I made a `str_replace` on a URL encoded string. Even using `urldecode` afterwards the URL was not correctly generated for `curl`, `file_get_contents`, ...

The correct URL should be something like this

http://domain.com/subfolder/another_subfolder/index.php?id=1234&tx_manager_pi9[parameter]=###param1###&tx_manager_pi9[category]=###param2###&&tx_manager_pi9[action]=getInfos&tx_manager_pi9[controller]=Finder&&cHash=123456789001233455332

i.e. without `&amp;`, `%23`, `%5B`, `%5D`

Answer (score 1):

You have a `,` instead of a `;` in your second code block.

Comment: Thanks Aram, but this is not the problem.

Comment: Hmm... That would give you a Server Error page is all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you required to be "logged in" to the site that you're visiting? That would explain why it's working in your browser and not through your server script.

If all else is the same, your browser and the PHP functions you listed should return the same results.

Could you provide the actual URL for us to test?

**EDIT:** Based on the URL you provided, it's working fine for me:

```
php > $test = file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/user/user_neu/index.php?id=16518&tx_stusermanager_pi9%5Bindications%5D=1&tx_stusermanager_pi9%5Bcategory%5D=cure&tx_stusermanager_pi9%5Baction%5D=getHousesByIndications&tx_stusermanager_pi9%5Bcontroller%5D=HouseFinder&cHash=88230660f01ads34d73a199b82e976");
php > var_dump($test);
string(29) "16,15,14,13,12,11,17,19,22"
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you're generating that URL but it seems to be incorrect. You have "&amp;" in the URL, which is the HTML encoding for an ampersand (&). The &amp; should only be used in your actual HTML to generate a &. Having that in your URL will break it. Instead, you want to use the actual & symbole by itself.

Comment: I think the problem was that the URL was URL-encoded. Doing a `str_replace` on this encoded URL leads to a wrong result (even a later decoding doesn't help). Using the "unencoded" URL will lead to the desired results. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes I know it was URL encoded, that's what I was hinting towards ;) I'm happy my hinting was sufficient and you got the rest figured out on your own!